# How to access browser's DocumentFragment nodes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For the page [chrome://history](http://chrome://history), in `Developer Tools`, the DOM Elements tree shows nodes of type `DocumentFragment` like the following `#shadow-root (open)` which you can see selected in the screenshot below:

[image: devtools screenshot]

My question is how to use querySelector or another Javascript method to select such nodes ?

Unlike what another answer in this site suggested, `DocumentFragment.querySelector` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot),

> The ShadowRoot interface of the Shadow DOM API is the root node of a DOM subtree that is rendered separately from a document's main DOM tree.
>
> You can retrieve a reference to an element's shadow root using its [Element.shadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot) property, provided it was created using [Element.attachShadow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) with the mode option set to open.

---

In your case, it looks like you need to do

```
var shroot = document.getElementById('history-app').shadowRoot
                     .getElementById('history').shadowRoot;
```

As you can see, we (apparently) have to browse down the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) step-by-step. I.e. trying for example to access the `'history'` element directly won't work since it is itself inside a `shadowRoot`.